# Parsing Nested Bson Input

Tags: json, mongodb, pentaho, bson

I am taking input from Mongo DB. Sample layout below:

```
{ "_id" : "CLIENT1:11860, "clientName" : "CLIENT1", "startTime" : { "$date" : 1407470732000 }, "endTime" : { "$date" : 1407472532000 }, "espSentStats" : { "SENT_CLIENT1" : { "TRIGGER1" : 6 }, "SENT_CLIENT2" : { "TRIGGER2" : 8 } } } 

{ "_id" : "CLIENT1:15108, "clientName" : "CLIENT1", "startTime" : { "$date" : 1407470732000 }, "endTime" : { "$date" : 1407472532000 }, "espSentStats" : { "SENT_CLIENT2" : { "TRIGGER3" : 2 } } }
```

The complication is that there is no fixed occurrence frequency of `SENT_CLIENT` or `TRIGGER`.

It is possible that there are one or multiple `SENT_CLIENTs` with one or multiple `TRIGGERs`.

It is all nested in `espSentStats`. I need the count for each SENT_CLIENT and TRIGGER.

How do I parse it.

I have access to `MongoDB, UNIX and Pentaho` as far as technology stack is concerned.

Comment: Could you describe your data and use case more? I think you want to consider a different data model but I don't want to make recommendations without a decent understanding of the requirements of the use case.

Comment: @wdberkeley Sure...
Let me try to explain the data more. Here id, clientname, endtime, senttime will occur in once every row. Inside espSentStats, there is ClientName. Inside every clientName, there is Trigger and its corresponding count. There can be one or more clientnames. Even one clientname can occur multiple times as it can have multiple trigger values.